# Periodic KeyError in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, random

I want to replace the empty values in the dataframe using random already existing values, while maintaining the weights so that the correlation does not suffer and the data is not lost.

```
def nan_fill_random(column_name, nan):
for i in range(len(column_name)):
    if column_name[i] == nan:
        column_name[i] = random.choice(column_name[column_name != nan])
    else:
        continue
```

I wrote a function, but it **periodically** throws a `KeyError`: and the value has different numbers, I assume indexes. Also, when you restart the cell, it can either disappear or be updated.

```
nan_fill_random(data['education'], 'unknown')
```

Here is the error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 14563

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4720/2723938638.py in <module>
----> 1 nan_fill_random(data['education'], 'unknown')

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4720/1980306790.py in nan_fill_random(column_name, nan)
      2     for i in range(len(column_name)):
      3         if column_name[i] == nan:
----> 4             column_name[i] = random.choice(column_name[column_name != nan])
      5         else:
      6             continue

W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in choice(self, seq)
    344         """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
    345         # raises IndexError if seq is empty
--> 346         return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
    347 
    348     def shuffle(self, x, random=None):

W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

W:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 14563
```

Comment: Most likely the problem lies in this part of the code
`random.choice(column_name[column_name != nan])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def nan_fill_random(column_name, nan):
    
    list_values = set(column_name)
    
    try : 
        list_values.remove(nan)
    except : 
        return(column_name)
    
    column_name = column_name.apply(lambda x: x if x != nan else random.choice(list(list_values)))
        
    return(column_name)
```

Comment: The code does not check the value for Nan, and can select and insert it again.

Comment: with this condition if x != nan , I check if the value is different than Nan if it's the case then I do nothing else I replace the value with random.choice(list_values)

Comment: In list_values remain nan, and random selects them. I tried to replace `list_values = column_name[column_name != nan]` but the code then throws an KeyError, although when displaying this dataset, it has no values Nan

Comment: you don't have to do this because I remove nan from list_value with : list_values.remove(nan) , so when yo random selects on list_value there is no nan

Comment: I understood you, tested the code, and for some reason, the "unknown" still remain, although their number decreases with each time the cell is launched

Comment: yes sorry we have to use set and not use list can you try the new version please

Comment: because when we use a list remove can not work is there is more than 1 nan.   exemple list_value [1,2,3,nan,nan,nan] become [1,2,3,nan,nan] and is we use set list_value become [1,2,3,nan] then [1,2,3]

Comment: `TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: because random.choice use only list so I transform my set in list now it should work

Comment: Just fix the tabs in the code for the last `return`